# Calculating distance between geo coordinates from a mysql database

Tags: mysql, coordinates, distance, latitude-longitude, geo

In my project i get geo coordinates from my users and i want a result sorted by distance from my mysql database. But the distance is 30% more or less what i get when i check google maps.

user data = `$latitude` & `$longitude`

my current query:

```
$sql = "SELECT *, (((acos(sin((" . $latitude . "*pi()/180)) * "
            . "sin((`latitude`*pi()/180))+"
            . "cos((" . $latitude . "*pi()/180)) * "
            . "cos((`latitude`*pi()/180)) * "
            . "cos(((" . $longitude . "- `longitude`)*pi()/180))))*180/pi())*60*1.1515*1.609344)*1.5 "
            . "as distance FROM `partners` HAVING distance <= '10' ORDER BY distance ASC LIMIT 0, 25";
```

Any tips on improving this?

- https://www.miammiam.lu/en/livraison/Differdange

Comment: Google maps is probably calculating the driving distance, this formula is the geographic distance.

Comment: oh, true... thanks